# how to get the result of multiplying two numbers

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I am trying to take a float as an arg input and do an equation in assembly using c only to get input and return the result.

How do i store the result into r?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float a, r;

    if (argc != 2) { printf("Invalid number of arguments"); }

    a = atof(argv[1]);

    printf("2*%f = ", a);

    __asm {
        mov eax, a
        mov ebx, 0x40000000//2.0
        mul ebx
        mov r, eax// always 0
    }

    printf("%f \n", r);

    return r;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to put the operands in the xmm registers and do a floating point multiply. The assembly code in the question treats `a` like an `int`, and multiplies it by a billion (approximately).